# Adding a custom AuthenticationHandler to a list of external login providers

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-authenticationhandler

I'm using ASP.NET Core 3.1, and I have multiple external login providers configured:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddDeviantArt(d => {
        d.Scope.Add("feed");
        d.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:DeviantArt:ClientId"];
        d.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:DeviantArt:ClientSecret"];
        d.SaveTokens = true;
    })
    .AddTwitter(t => {
        t.ConsumerKey = Configuration["Authentication:Twitter:ConsumerKey"];
        t.ConsumerSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Twitter:ConsumerSecret"];
        t.SaveTokens = true;
    });
```

I'd like to create a custom `AuthenticationProvider` that, instead of redirecting to another website, asks for that website's "API key" and treats that as the access token. (The website in question does not support any version of OAuth.)

Before actually hooking it up, I want to test that I can get a custom `AuthenticationProvider` working at all, so I found one that implements HTTP Basic authentication:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> {
    public CustomAuthenticationHandler(
        IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options,
        ILoggerFactory logger,
        UrlEncoder encoder,
        ISystemClock clock)
        : base(options, logger, encoder, clock) { }

    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync() {
        if (!Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization")) {
            return AuthenticateResult.NoResult();
        }

        if (!AuthenticationHeaderValue.TryParse(Request.Headers["Authorization"], out AuthenticationHeaderValue headerValue)) {
            return AuthenticateResult.NoResult();
        }

        if (!"Basic".Equals(headerValue.Scheme, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
            return AuthenticateResult.NoResult();
        }

        byte[] headerValueBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(headerValue.Parameter);
        string userAndPassword = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(headerValueBytes);
        string[] parts = userAndPassword.Split(':');
        if (parts.Length != 2) {
            return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Invalid Basic authentication header");
        }
        string user = parts[0];
        string password = parts[1];

        bool isValidUser = true;

        if (!isValidUser) {
            return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Invalid username or password");
        }
        var claims = new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user) };
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, Scheme.Name);
        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, Scheme.Name);
        return AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);
    }

    protected override async Task HandleChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties) {
        Response.Headers["WWW-Authenticate"] = $"Basic realm=\"Custom realm name here\", charset=\"UTF-8\"";
        await base.HandleChallengeAsync(properties);
    }
}
```

I added this to Startup.cs:

```
.AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, CustomAuthenticationHandler>("Test", "Testing", o => { })
```

The problem is that the `HandleAuthenticateAsync` method is never called. The other solutions I find to this problem generally say you need to make it the "default" authentication scheme, but I don't want this to interfere with how the other external login providers are set up.

Is there a way I can get this working without changing the default authentication scheme or adding additional attributes to my controllers or actions?

Answer (score 0):

You need add a default Scheme when you add `AddAuthentication`

like `services.AddAuthentication("Test")`

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve the problem for an "external login providers" scenario. Specifying a default scheme doesn't seem to have any effect, and it's not desired anyway because multiple custom schemes need to be available to the user.